# Calculate SUM based on date

Tags: excel

This is driving me nuts and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

I have an excel table where my turnover is in with the date of incoming invoices. The date is in format `ddmmjjj` and is in column C.

I want to calculate my turnover on my dashboard. The total turnover is in column G.

The formula I use is:

```
=SUM(IF(MONTH(Sheet1!C:C)=2;Sheet!G:G;))
```

But this formula keeps giving me the total turnover... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `=SUMIF()` will work for you. `=SUMIF()` is available on Excel 2007 and later versions.

Comment: Can you put some sample data for better understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [`SUMIF` function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIF-function-169B8C99-C05C-4483-A712-1697A653039B) in Excel, which allows you to sum up certain cells if the values in associated cells match a criteria:

```
SUMIF(range, criteria, [sum_range])
```

In your case, you'd want to extract the month for the dates in column C into another column (say column X holds the month for the dates in column C), and then:

```
=SUMIF(Sheet1!X:X, 2, Sheet1!G:G)
```

Answer (score 2):

The formula you are using is correct, however you need to enter it as an *[array formula](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7D94A64E-3FF3-4686-9372-ECFD5CAA57C7?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1)* (via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>).

```
=SUM(IF(MONTH(Sheet1!C:C)=2,Sheet1!G:G,0))
```